# CENTER align text when using StyledCellLabelProvider

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I use a StyledCellLabelProvider to format text string as 'Hyperlink'.

```
// Column for the link
TableViewerColumn col2 = createTableViewerColumn("Link", 100, 1, viewer);
col2.setLabelProvider(new StyledCellLabelProvider() {
    @Override
    public void update(ViewerCell cell)
    {
        Object element = cell.getElement();
        if(element instanceof Person)
        {
            Person person = (Person) cell.getElement();

            /* make text look like a link */
            StyledString text = new StyledString();
            StyleRange myStyledRange = new StyleRange(0, person.getLocation().length(), Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE), null);
            myStyledRange.underline = true;
            text.append(person.getLocation(), StyledString.DECORATIONS_STYLER);
            cell.setText(text.toString());

            StyleRange[] range = { myStyledRange };
            cell.setStyleRanges(range);

            super.update(cell);
        }
    }
});
```

I also set text align of TableViewerColumn is CENTER but after using this style the text is left align.

How can I set CENTER align of text and change the cursor into link cursor when touch to the text?

Thanks